# Segmentation fault while accessing struct filled with data read from pipe

Tags: c

I keep on having a segmentation fault while trying to access a struct named Request, filled with data read from a pipe.  What's wrong with my code? The error is thrown here with a simple printf trying to print the name field

STRUCT DEFINITION:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char code;      
    pid_t pid;       
    char *name;      
    char *object;    
    int id;          
    void *buffer;    
    size_t size;     
} Request;
```

WRITER CODE:

```
request.code   = MANADDUSER;   /* macro defining a char */
request.pid    = getpid();
request.name   = argument1;   /* dinamycally allocated string */
request.object = NULL;
request.id     = 0;
request.buffer = NULL;
request.size   = 0;
if((fifoto = open(FIFOTOMMBOXD, O_WRONLY)) == -1)   logMmboxman("error in opening FIFOTO\n", 1); 
else                                                logMmboxman("opened FIFOTO\n", 0);  

if((write(fifoto, &request, sizeof(Request))) != sizeof(Request))   logMmboxman("error in writing FIFOTO\n", 1);
else                                                                logMmboxman("written on FIFOTO\n", 0);
close(fifoto);
```

READER CODE:

```
if((fifoto = open(FIFOTOMMBOXD, O_RDWR)) == -1)   logMmboxd("error in opening FIFOTO\n", 1); 
else                                              logMmboxd("opened FIFOTO\n", 0);  

if((read(fifoto, &request, sizeof(Request))) != sizeof(Request))   logMmboxd("error in reading FIFOTO\n", 1);
else                                                               logMmboxd("read from FIFOTO\n", 0);
close(fifoto);

printf("%s\n", request.name);
```

Comment: Please don't write tags in titles.

Comment: Your code is not a testcase; in particular, it does not show the creation of the `Request` object.

Comment: where did you pick up this strange code formatting style?  I have to say it's one I've never seen before.

Comment: ok I won't use tags anymore. I posted just these statements to focus on the core of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably sending the address of `Request.name` over the pipe. When the receiver gets it, `Request.name` obviously points to invalid memory.

Comment: The string is dinamically allocated within the writing process. However the reading process is a small server application, thrown with a fork+exec by the writing process. Once thrown, the parent process starts sending data over the son process within the pipe. I guess I can't read the memory allocated to the parent process within the son process, if is that so how can I access that string? Writing on the pipe the whole content itself?

Comment: You could settle on a fixed size for the string and declare it as an array or you could write your own serialization / deserialization  functions. I would go for the first option (as I have fully explored the second in the passed, with little benefit).

Answer (score 2):

This can be fixed by altering the structure to something like:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char   code;      
    pid_t  pid;       
    char   name[SOMESIZE];
    char   object[SOMEOTHERSIZE];
    int    id;          
    size_t size;     
} Request;
```

and make corresponding changes to the reader and writer.  If the pipe is connected between processes, the addresses contained by `name`, `object`, and `buffer` are meaningless in the new context.

Comment: I was pondering this solution too. But in this little project I have to use some structs defined by the specifications sheet (?): in this structs every field is defined as a pointer (char * for strings and void * for data buffers). Then this structs must be passed to the server process (son process in this case forked() by the first process which sends the data across the pipe). If I can't access this memory region within the son process, how am I supposed to deal with this data and buffers allocated by and along the parent associated memory?

Comment: There must be some specification for how the pointers are represented.  One that I ran across many times in the 1980s was that the pointers were relative to the beginning of the structure.  But still, there is something missing here.  The `name` has to have characters in the message somewhere, or they are encoded somehow, perhaps by pointing to a standard string table on both ends.  Either way, a significant piece of the puzzle is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing the flag you expect to the open within the Reader's code?

I would have expected you want O_RDONLY rather than O_RDWR.

Comment: Is more complicated than this: the process reading the pipe keep on reading in a while(1) the pipe to work on the data written on it. If nobody is writing on the pipe and the process open it with the O_RDONLY flag it will throw out a -1 with the open call, and I'll have to handle the situation. With the O_RDWR flag it will block until the process itself write on the pipe or somebody else do it.